# Can't click on tabs to switch fragment

Tags: android, swipeview

So now I finally got the swipe views to work but now I can only swipe to change tab and when I click a tab, nothing happens.

My code: http://pastebin.com/p3Cs1qm1

I think the problem is at line 31 because when I have that line uncommented I get the error "Unknown entity 'pager'" and it might be that line which allows me to change tabs my clicking on them but then I have to know how to remove the error message.

Answer (score 1):

> then I have to know how to remove the error message.

Step #1: Add a data member named `pager` to the activity.

Step #2: Have your `findViewById()` call in `initialisePaging()` set the `pager` data member, instead of a local variable.

This way, `pager` will be available to your `ActionBar.TabListener`.

Comment: This sounds like a solution but unfortunately I don't really know how to convert your steps into code. Haven't really got a grip about that yet but I'm working on it. So basically, how should I write the solution in code?